# jQuery validate and alert

Tags: jquery, validation, alert

I'm using an external validation library to check whetever fields have been filled out or not. This works fine.

I then want to show an alert, when all fields have been filled out correctly and the user hits submit.

Here's the code:

```
<select id="selectsizes" class="required">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<input type="Text" id="txtName" name="Name" value="" class="required">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Form").submit(function() {
    if ($('.required').val() != "") {
      alert("Thank you.");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

I have more fields in the original form, this is just for the sake of explanation.
If I either choose an option from the select or fill out the input field, the alert will fire upon pressing submit. It shouldn't fire, before all validation errors are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check each input for a value individually, and then check if they all have a value etc, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Form").submit(function () {
        var val = $.map($('.required'), function (el, i) {
            if (!$.trim(el.value).length) return el;
        });
        if (!val.length) {
            alert("Thank you.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/g3Z6a/)

Answer (score 0):

create a var, for example `var error = false;`

Cycle through all your input and selects if you got an input which is not filled set the var to true `error = true;`

finally:

```
if (!error) {
  alert("Thank you.");
  return false;
}
```

you can cycle through your required fields with:

```
$('.required').each(function() {
  //DO STUFF
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    error = true;
  }
});
```